# Code in latex for braces

Tags: editors, winedt

In LaTeX text, I sometimes need 'unpaired' parenthesis - `(` without `)` or vice versa; however, in such a case, delimiter check macro reports error. I found a simple solution: `\symbol{40}` and `\symbol{41}`, which aren't recognized as delimiters. The same works for brackets `[` and `]` (decimal codes are 91 and 93 respectively), but doesn't work for braces `{` and `}`. Their codes are 123 and 125 respectively, but `\symbol{123}` and `\symbol{125}` produce something like dash and quote. I use fontenc LCY, trying both text and math modes.

I've found solution:`\textbraceleft` and `\textbraceright`, but why `\symbol` doesn't work in such a case?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using the unpaired parentheses in text or math?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can you post a minimal compilable document showing what you're doing?  In math mode, the way to get an unpaired delimiter with `\left` and `\right` is to use `.` as the empty delimiter. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Do you prefer to have the delimiter check macro working instead of the readability of the text?

Comment: Is this in fact a question about your *editing* environment? In which case, you need to tell us which editor you use.

Comment: egreg, thanks for reply. These braces (brackets, parenthesis) are math symbols within text: `aa aaa aaaa $\symbol{40} $..` However, it is not the problem to use them as text, even more convenient.

Comment: Sigur, thanks for reply. The text is rather huge (book of more than 100 p ), so delimiter cheking is important. On the other hand, there are not a big amount of unpared ones, so the readibility  remains well.

Comment: Alan Munn, thanks for reply. I'm using WinEdt, but the question is not **'How to do it'** (I've already found the solution), but **'Why `\symbol{123}` doesn't work'**?

Comment: But 'Why `\symbol{123}` doesn't work?' depends on who is actually doing the checking: LaTeX, your editing environment, or some custom macro that's doing things manually.  (PS, if you put @ in front of a username, you'll get autocompletion as well as sending a notification to that person.)

Comment: Teepeemm, it really doesn't. No error messages are produced, but `{` isn't printed. Instead, something like dash is shown

Comment: what fonts are used in your documents?  if you are using computer modern, the braces are not present in the usual text fonts; they are drawn instead from the symbol font, `cmsy`, where they are present at positions "66 and "67 (102 and 103).   only in `cmtt` are they in the "usual" ascii positions.

Comment: barbara beeton, thanks for reply. I don't switch to other fonts explicitly. Fontenc is `LCY` (cyrillic encoding); as I remember, it uses `cmr` (computer modern). I tried both text and math mode, result was the same.

Comment: When replying to a person you should write an at-sign before the username, e.g. @AlanMunn instead of Alan Munn. That way the user is notified of your comment, making it much more likely that he or she sees your reply. (You as the owner of the post is always notified.) Tab-completion of usernames is available, but you can only ping one user per comment.

Comment: it is a really bad idea to use `\symbol` with a number, even when it works. the idea of encoding-specific commands such as `\{` or `\textbraceleft` are that latex knows the encoding currently in use and uses the correct number.  If you use a fixed number but the encoding for whatever reason changes then you will get the wrong character with no warning. `\symbol{123}` works but it does not mean make any particular character it means "print whatever character happens to be in position 123 of the current font" So it works as designed but is not often what you want to do.

Comment: when i need to match an "unmatched" delimiter, i usually cut the input line short and add a comment at the end of the line with the "matching" member of the pair.  things to watch out for: make sure to leave a space before the `%`; you can't reflow a paragraph when this method is used because it might lose or gain something additional if the comment is repositioned; it doesn't work easily with "open interval" coding (`]a,b[`).

Comment: @barbarabeeton and others, thanks for replis and useful advices. I'm going to go away from `\symbol{}`, the idea of `% <closing symbol>`looks much better.

Answer (score 4):

I guess from the comments that you mean the editor delimiter check.

Winedt can get confused by lonely parens:

[image]

The easiest way to get around this type of problem is to add the missing delimiter behind a comment sign:

[image]

Using commands works too, but \symbol{X} is not a good idea as the number X can depend on the active font encoding.

Comment: Good answer. I note that it is best to "somehow" show both of the pair, even if one half is commented out. Reason: I often detect coding errors by counting the number of left braces and right braces, etc., in a text editor.